# Java8 stream lines and aggregate with action on terminal line

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

### Question

How to execute an action after the last item of an ordered stream is processed but before it's closed ?
This Action should be able to inject zero or more items in the stream pipe.

### Context

I've got a very large file of the form :

```
MASTER_REF1
    SUBREF1
    SUBREF2
    SUBREF3
MASTER_REF2
MASTER_REF3
    SUBREF1
    ...
```

Where SUBREF (if any) is applicable to MASTER_REF and both are complex objects (you can imagine it somewhat *like* JSON).

On first look I tried something like :

```
public void process(Path path){
    MyBuilder builder = new MyBuilder();
    Files.lines(path)
        .map(line->{
            if(line.charAt(0)==' '){
                builder.parseSubRef(line);
                return null;
            }else{
                Result result = builder.build()
                builder.parseMasterRef(line);
                return result;
            }
        })
        //eliminate null
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        //some processing on results
        .map(Utils::doSomething)
        //terminal op
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
}
```

**[EDIT] using `forEach` here was a bad idea ... the good way was to use `forEachOrdered`**

But, for obvious reasons, the last item is never appended to the stream : it is still being built.

Therefore I'm wondering how to flush it in the stream at the end of line processing.

Comment: You shouldn't be using *stateful* functions in `map`. If you want to rely on the order of the lines and keep state based on it, a conventional loop would be more appropriate.

Comment: It could get implemented with a variant of mutable reduction, however, the code will get way more complicated than a simple loop…

Comment: @RealSkeptic I know ... I hate this design, yet this was a first attempt.

Comment: I think there are two questions in my problem. Therefore I've created a new one for the other aspect : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868927/java8-how-to-aggregate-objects-from-a-stream

Comment: @Holger I have the same feeling but can't figure it out. Could you please give it a try in my other post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868927/java8-how-to-aggregate-objects-from-a-stream (+ this would allow me to be stateless as mentionned by RealSkeptic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question sounds confusing. The Stream is closed when the `close()` method is called explicitly or when try-with-resources construct is used. In your code sample the stream is not closed at all. To perform custom action before the stream is closed, you can just write something at the end of try-with-resource statement.

In your case it seems that you want to concatenate some bogus entry to the stream. There's `Stream.concat()` method to do this:

```
Stream.concat(Files.lines(path), Stream.of("MASTER"))
      .map(...) // do all your other steps
```

---

Finally note that my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which enhances the Stream API provides partial reduction methods which are good to parse multi-line entries. The same thing can be done using [`StreamEx.groupRuns()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#groupRuns-java.util.function.BiPredicate-) which combines adjacent elements into intermediate list by given `BiPredicate`:

```
public void process(Path path){
    StreamEx.of(Files.lines(path))
        .groupRuns((line1, line2) -> line2.charAt(0) == ' ')
        // Now Stream elements are List<String> starting with MASTER and having
        // all subref strings after that
        .map(record -> {
           MyBuilder builder = new MyBuilder();
           builder.parseMasterRef(record.get(0));
           record.subList(1, record.size()).forEach(builder::parseSubRef);
           return record.build();
        })
        //eliminate null
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        //some processing on results
        .map(Utils::doSomething)
        //terminal op
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Now you don't need to use side-effect operations.

Comment: Thanks ! I need to check something but I think that using `concat` + a bogus entry could be it (yet uglier than I hoped ;)). You've deciphered my question correctly : I must admit that "before it's closed" was ideed confusing)

Comment: Ok, my example was worthless : I used `forEach` instead of `forEachOrderd` and lines were mixed up. BTW You should cross post the second part of your answer in my other question :)

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem here is that you are streaming - effectively - two types of records and this makes it difficult to manage because streams are primarily for amorphous data.

I would pre-process the file data and collect it into `MasterAndSub` records. You can then `groupingBy` these by the `Master` field.

```
class MasterAndSub {

    final String master;
    final String sub;

    public MasterAndSub(String master, String sub) {
        this.master = master;
        this.sub = sub;
    }

}

/**
 * Allows me to use a final Holder of a mutable value.
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
class Holder<T> {

    T it;

    public T getIt() {
        return it;
    }

    public T setIt(T it) {
        return this.it = it;
    }

}

public void process(Path path) throws IOException {
    final Holder<String> currentMaster = new Holder<>();
    Files.lines(path)
            .map(line -> {
                if (line.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    return new MasterAndSub(currentMaster.getIt(), line);
                } else {
                    return new MasterAndSub(currentMaster.setIt(line), null);
                }
            })
            ...
```

Comment: In most cases it could be a good idea, but unfortunately my data file is way bigger than the total amount of RAM+SWAP ... a terminal operation would saturate availiable resources (by design I need to keep groups in memory because are to be transformed afterwards)